# H264 Encoder / Decoder Writing from Scratch?

Tags: h.264

I think about writing a H264 encoder / decoder from scratch to be able to integrate the tech into a composite product. The first implementation would be written in Java.

I am used to implement scientific papers and such so I should at least bring in the basic math understanding.

What would be the best start and what should I focus on. I know that basically H264 is a mix of existing techniques.

What is are the most important things to implement?

Any idea about how much hours of work the first useful version will take.

The main objective is very fast while maintaining good compression.

Comment: why don't you just use ffmpeg? it's even disgusting to use the library. why bother to write something similar?

Comment: By the way if you just want an encoder/ decoder check libx264. it's already opensource in case you want to change something.

Comment: The commercial solution of x264 is subject to licensing. Also I want to adapt the whole show in a modified version.

Comment: You can also have a look at the reference software (JM), also open-source and I don't think there is any licensing. Otherwise, I would guess at least hundreds of hours for a first standard compatible version...

Comment: why H.264 and not H.265? ;)

Comment: I upvoted the answer below. The correct answer: don't, especially in Java. Unless you can gather a team of experienced algorithmists and work on it for several years, you won't be able to beat open source implementations (x264, openh264), and any software codec will loose to hardware one in terms of speed.

Comment: Thats correct. The idea is not to implement the full specs. I needed real-time compression and when I implemented it in Java I can translate it easily to C in a couple of days since I still have the test suite. Also I do not need to beat something since I need a just good enough version. I settled with the idea to use the VP8/9 ideas and build around those.

Comment: But until now using JPEG + PNG and a small / lightweight container implementation is now enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How many hours? Maybe 20,000. The decoder specification alone is over 750 page document. And the decoder is the easy part.

Answer (score 0):

After consideration :), I now will still use my own solution based on PNG and JPEG while not using motion vectors. I simply wrote a small solution I can compress parts of the image based on those and use filters to degrade the quality by applying sorts of blur or reduce the number of colors or even resolution. Works well enough for now.

If I need better quality I start looking at VP9 in more detail.

The only draw back is no hardware encoding support which might force me / us to look into H264 again.

Currently I can deliver 60+ frames for every days situation and scale down to 15 frames per second for video content along with bad quality but it is good enough to grab a security cam screen and see if something is wrong.